Jataka Number of the Bodhisatta's aspiration for Buddhahood?

Please someone know the Jataka (past lives of the Buddha) reference number of the Bodhisatta's aspiration for Buddhahood? As Sumedha in the city of Amaravatī?


The E. B. Cowell Jataka edition


Secondly how many Buddhas ago was it?
What was the Buddhas name?
Finally how many aeons was it between Buddha Gotama and that Buddha?


notes:

"four asaṃkhyeya and a hundred thousand kalpas ago" (from memory)


The second and third question may come from secondary sources.

Where does the story of Bodhisatta's aspiration for Buddhahood come from?
The three main sources found thus far are:
(1) Jātakanidānaṁ - The introduction to the Jātaka's

The Nidānakathā: Introduction to the Jātaka Stories,  translation by T. W. Rhys Davids (online)
The Jātaka or Stories of the Buddha’s Former Births, Translation Books
Jataka With Its Commentary, Pali Books

(2) The Jinacaritaṁ - The Account of the Great Conqueror

Jinacarita, or "The Career of the Conqueror", English see p164, Charles Duroiselle.
The Life of the Victorious Buddha,  English & Pali, Anandajoti Bhikkhu
Poem on the life of ... Written in Sri Lanka. (13th century C.E.) PTS Book

(3) The Buddhavaṃsa - also known as the Chronicles of Buddha

They describes the life of Gautama Buddha and of the twenty-four Buddhas who preceded him... It is the fourteenth book of the Khuddaka Nikāya, which in turn is the fifth and last division of the Sutta Piṭaka. Wikipedia
"Thus the Buddhavaṃsa Text refers only briefly to the appearance of Buddha Dīpaṅkarā in the story of Sumeda. It is only in the Buddhavaṃsa Commentary that we find the full story of Buddha Dīpaṅkarā, with details of events in chronicle order, starting from the episode of His rebirth in the abode of Tusitā Gods."
The Great Chronicle of Buddhas, by Ven. Mingun Sayadaw

What is the key points of the Buddha's past Great Aspiration Life?

Tradition tells us that four asaṅkheyyas  and a hundred thousand cycles ago there was a city called Amaravatī. In this city there dwelt a brahmin named Sumedha... **


The story opens with the youth Sumedha gaining insight into the nature of reality following the passing away of his parents, which is followed by his renunciation of the home life and very successful spiritual practice in the Himālayas.
He then comes into contact with a true spiritual teacher, the Buddha Dīpaṅkara, and being inspired by the meeting, he gives up the chance of liberation then and there, and makes his aspiration to attain Buddhahood himself, in order to help all living beings cross the great flood of Saṁsāra.
The Life of the Victorious Buddha


"What! If I were to make a bridge for the wise, the great Sage and clergy that accompany him, by laying me down in the mud?"
"Better for me complete extinction, when I have made the people cross over the ocean of rebirths in the boat of the Law and have brought them to Nirvana!"
"This ascetic, in times to come, shall become a fully enlightened Buddha, by the name Gotama!
"The Career of the Conqueror"

What is the origin stated of the stories?

I proceed to recite a Commentary upon this Jātaka, illustrating as it does the infinite efficacy of the actions of great men – a commentary based upon the method of exposition current among the inmates of the Great Monastery (Mahāvihāra). And I do so at the personal request of the elder Atthadassī, who lives apart from the world and ever dwells with his fraternity, and who desires the perpetuation of this chronicle of Buddha; and likewise of Buddhamitta the tranquil and wise, sprung from the race of Mahiṁsāsaka, skilled in the canons of interpretation; and moreover of the monk Buddhadeva of clear intellect.
May all good men lend me their favourable attention while I speak!
The Nidānakathā


"The author Ven. Medhaṅkara follows for the most part the story as it is found in the Jātakanidānaṁ..." **

How long ago was the aspiration?

four asaṅkheyyas  and a hundred thousand cycles ago (v1 jinacarita) & Jātakanidānaṁ


An asankheyya of Mahakalpa is said to be 10¹⁴⁰ in Pali Dictionary,Childers, Robert Cæsar by the article World Cycles when a Buddha Appears

A Mahakalpa is one cycle of cosmic expansion and contraction.

So four asankheyya and a hundred thousand Mahakalpa using this calculation would be: 400 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 100 000 aeons.


How rare is it to come in contact with the Dhamma of a Buddha as a human?
Just to give a comparison from the core suttas, we can take a simile of how rare it is to come in contact with a Buddha and the shining Dhamma as a human...

[SN 11.48] “Bhikkhus, suppose that this great earth had become one mass of water, and  a man would throw a yoke with a single hole upon it. An easterly wind would drive it westward; a westerly wind would drive it eastward; a northerly wind would drive it southward; a southerly wind would drive it northward.
There was a blind turtle which would come to the surface once every hundred years. What do you think, bhikkhus, would that blind turtle, coming to the surface once every hundred years, insert its neck into that yoke with a single hole?”
“It would be by chance, venerable sir, that that blind turtle, coming to the surface once every hundred years, would insert its neck into that yoke with a single hole.”
“So too, bhikkhus, it is by chance that one obtains the human state; by chance that a Tathāgata, an Arahant, a Perfectly Enlightened One arises in the world; by chance that the Dhamma and Discipline proclaimed by the Tathāgata shines in the world. [The Connected Discourses of the Buddha] ...


If we take this to be accurate and referring to the worlds oceans: the oceans cover an area of 361 million km² so we times this by 1 000 000 square meters, times 4 to get the size of a 0.25 meter yoke.
Once every hundred years the opportunity is 1 in 1 quad trillion 444 trillion chance (1 in 1,444,000,000,000,000). This is how rare the mentioned opportunity is once every 100 years.
Another mind boggling calculation is on an aeon defined by these calculations here as 1.2 sextillion years. (sutta: Aeon silk cloth simile). Remember that nama rupa take time to form, so our modern calculations using billions don't take that into consideration, see the dot dot dot in the diagrams of modern universal formation theories.

